# "mvn quarkus:dev" throws "NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext"

Tags: logging, quarkus

When I run "mvn quarkus:dev" on my hello world app, deliberately using our big parent pom, I get this:

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:0.22.0:dev (default-cli) @ my-quarkus-example ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:110)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:27)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:551)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
        ...
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2490)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.<clinit>(DevModeMain.java:43)
```

Both `LogManager` and `LogContext` reside in `jboss-logmanager-embedded-1.0.3.jar`. The version in my dependency match those in the quarkus `0.22.0` pom. In IntelliJ, I can click through from `LogManager` to `LogContext`. My hello world app does not do any logging, just a hello REST service.

Result of "mvn dependency:tree":

```
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar:0.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-undertow:jar:0.22.0:compile
...
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-core:jar:0.22.0:compile
...
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager-embedded:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:2.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logging:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the whole dependency tree? It looks weird. Anything specific in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I am extending the `kie-parent` pom (deliberately, it's an internal requirement). [That pom](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap/blob/master/pom.xml#L47) defines a lot of dependency versions (which have been known to be inconsistent which each other, at times). I'd like to figure out what the problem is so I can fix the kie-parent pom while I am writing this example.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Full dependency tree: https://gist.github.com/ge0ffrey/680f85f4bf8cda8c12d92618c317b07b

Answer (score 0):

Our parent `pom` had this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-common</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Changing that to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-common</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0.Final-format-001</version>
</dependency>
```

Made the quarkus error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext` go away.